# ValueError while inserting into a database

Tags: python, sql

I'm doing an insert to my DB and I'm inserting a string with an email.

Something like this:

```
cur.execute("insert into client values(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name, email, date,int(age)))
```

Then, when the variable `email` is `'email@outlook.com'`, Python throws me this message

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: email@outlook.com
```

My database has the following metadata:

```
name = varchar
email = varchar
date = date
age = integer
```

Does anybody knows what is happening?

Comment: for int its %d not %s

Comment: I think you want `%d` for an int. But your error message seems to indicate that `age` is actually "email@outlook.com".

Comment: i thought that too but, cant seem to find why is my age variable my email since i followed up everywhere doing prints and each time it follows the variable as a string

Comment: It's possible that the order of columns is different than you think. To avoid this issue, specify the column list in the SQL: `insert into client (name, email, date, age) values (?,?,?,?)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming from Python, not SQL.

Somehow, the name `age` is equal to the string `'email@outlook.com'`.  So, when you do `int(age)`, you get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> age = 'email@outlook.com'
>>> int(age)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'email@outlook.com'
>>>
```

You need to find where you accidentally assigned `age` to the email address and fix that.  I cannot tell exactly how you did this because the code is not posted, but it is usually because you unpacked an iterable incorrectly.  Something like:

```
name, email, date, age = ['Joe', 20, '11/12/2014', 'email@outlook.com']
```

which should be:

```
name, age, date, email = ['Joe', 20, '11/12/2014', 'email@outlook.com']
```

---

Additionally, you should never use string formatting to build SQL commands.  Instead, pass the arguments as a tuple and use `?` to refer to them:

```
cur.execute("insert into client values(?,?,?,?)", (name, email, date, age))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for
>   humorous example of what can go wrong).

Comment: thanks! the problem was in my client object changed email with age sorry! anyway tried to change my sql code with ? ? but postgres driver doesnt work with this!

Answer (score 0):

Never write INSERT statements like

```
 INSERT INTO Client VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Instead write

```
 INSERT INTO Client (Name, EmailAddress, StartDate, Age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The first version is extremely brittle. Even if it works when you first implement the program it's subject to breakage if you restructure the table -- breakage that might cause the program to fail or, worse, allow it to work but insert data into the wrong columns.

Also, when applying SQL statements in this manner you use untyped `?` placeholders for the parameters passed to the statement.  Those parameters will then be bound to the statement in a type-sensible, SQL injection safe manner without your needing to worry about escaping internal quote marks in names (for instance).